# Setting the argument's value in workflow c#

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, workflow-foundation, setvalue, workflow-foundation-4.5

I am using Windows Workflow Foundation .NET 4.5.2.
I have an issue regarding setting an argument of type `bool` (could be also a variable) in designer from inside CodeActivity.

In the designer, I set the argument `newProject` of type `bool` with direction `In`. (should it have another direction? i.e. `InOut`).

In code I want to set the argument from designer to value `true`.

```
 public class Inquire : CodeActivity
 {
    public InArgument<bool> newProject { get; set; }

    public InArgument<bool> rework { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("For a new project type 'new', for rework type 'rw'.");
         string inquire = Console.ReadLine();

         if (inquire == "new")
         {
             context.SetValue(newProject, true);
         }
         else
         {
             rework.Set(context, true);
         }
     }
 }
```

The argument in the designer is verified in a transition that enables me to get to the next state. If it is `true`, I can get to the next state.
The problem is that the argument in the designer does not receive the new value that is set in the code above. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the value back out the designer you need to make it either an Out argument or an InOut argument.

Comment: I set it in the designer and in code, but it didn't work. I tried with both InOut and Out.